# Strange behavior reading demensions from XML

Tags: android

This is my dimens XML file:

```
<resources>    
    <dimen name="time_text_size">20dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="artist_text_size">20dp</dimen>
</resources>
```

This is my code:

```
int timeSize = res.getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.time_text_size);
System.out.println("timeSize: " + timeSize);
int artistSize = res.getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.artist_text_size);
System.out.println("artistSize: " + artistSize);
```

This is the console's result:

```
08-10 16:48:44.705: I/System.out(11866): timeSize: 40
08-10 16:48:44.705: I/System.out(11866): artistSize: 20
```

And this is my reaction:
**WTF!?**

I get this error on my Tablet (Transformer Prime). On my Galaxy Nexus this works great and I got no problems with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

//actually you are running in xhdpi device

```
20 * 2 =40 px
```

if you have another `dimen.xml` in `values-hdpi` or `values-xhdpi` folder check the values are same that you might copy pasted there.

Comment: That was the problem. I forgot that there are several dimen.xml in other folders ;)